# SMPP 'Invalid Parameter Length.' Exception

Tags: php, smpp

I'm Using [onlinecity/php-smpp](https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp) library to create a SMPP client for first time and by running its example,I keep receive an exception which said:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'gateway\protocol\SmppException' with message 'Invalid Parameter Length.' in C:\wamp\www\html\gateway\protocol\smppclient.class.php on line 488

Now, my question is that is this message related to the SMPP server configuration or I'm missing something in my client code?
If this is related to server, how can I trace and troubleshoot that?

UPDATE:

```
    483     $pdu = new \SMPP\PDU($id, 0, $this->sequence_number, $pduBody);
    484     $this->sendPDU($pdu);
    485     
    486     $response=$this->readPDU_resp($this->sequence_number, $pdu->id);
    487         
    488         if ($response->status != \SMPP\ESME_ROK) throw new SmppException(\SMPP\getStatusMessage($response->status), $response->status);
```

Comment: Password length can be a regular problem... Is it longer than 8 characters?  Have you configured the client at all?

Comment: Can you paste lines 487-489?

Comment: @msturdy the password has exactly 8 characters length.

Comment: What's in the body of the pdu?

Comment: can you post more code?  Do you have a successfully bound connection at the point where you're sending the PDU?  What sort of PDU are you sending?

Comment: @msturdy I'm using the exact code like the library I mentioned has. Yes, the connection successfully bound with no error (ESME_ROK)

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Can you share some more code on here?  I don't understand why you're trying to achieve by sending the PDU, when there are methods (`sendSMS()`, `bindTransmitter()`) to accomplish most SMPP tasks simply... what's in $pduBody?

Comment: @msturdy thanks for your time :), As I said in first line of my post, I just use the simple example of this code: https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp/blob/c082b1a4b0dcd2cc551cc8845189edac3bd9399f/README.markdown not any more. I create a TSocket and SmppClient object. and try to bindTransmitter, then sendSMS. just that. But I receive fatal error.

Comment: Sorry @Rahman, I misunderstood.. that's the code from the lib itself.. Can you set debug on the connection (`$smpp->debug = true;
$transport->debug = true;`) and include details of the message you're sending? Beware not to post your username and password (which are included in the HEX output from the debug).  Posting your code will help too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33700/discussion-between-rahman-and-msturdy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I update library to newer (and windows-compatible) version: [onlinecity/php-smpp/windows-compatible](https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp/tree/windows-compatible)

Then add a single optional line of code:

```
SmppClient::$sms_null_terminate_octetstrings = false;
```

And Boom! Problem solved.